# Code to download pdf view in latest android

Tags: android

I am working in an NGO to provide education to slum children. Recently i have learned only Android for developing an app for providing then free e-books and notes developed by my friends and teacher. Name of my NGO is TRPWS(The Rising People Welfare Society)..New Delhi,India.

I am not able to find code to download pdf and view it.

Please help me by providing help in developing this code/app.

```
package org.example.ambika.pdf;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pdfView.fromAsset(pdfName)
                .pages(0, 2, 1, 3, 3, 3)
                .defaultPage(1)
                .showMinimap(false)
                .enableSwipe(true)
                .onDraw(onDrawListener)
                .onLoad(onLoadCompleteListener)
                .onPageChange(onPageChangeListener)
                .load();
    }
}
```

I don't have too much knowledge about Java and other languages .
Please Help Me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code,

```
new DownloadFile().execute(pdfUrl, pdffileName);
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>{

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {
            String fileUrl = strings[0];  
            String fileName = strings[1];  // pdf name
            String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
            File folder = new File(extStorageDirectory, "testthreepdf");
            folder.mkdir();

            File pdfFile = new File(folder, fileName);

            try{
                pdfFile.createNewFile();
            }catch (IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            FileDownloader.downloadFile(fileUrl, pdfFile);
            return null;
        }
    }



public class FileDownloader {
    private static final int  MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;

    public static void downloadFile(String fileUrl, File directory){
        try {

            URL url = new URL(fileUrl);
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            urlConnection.connect();

            InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(directory);
            int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();

            byte[] buffer = new byte[MEGABYTE];
            int bufferLength = 0;
            while((bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer))>0 ){
                fileOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
            }
            fileOutputStream.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

// add permission in Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```